# Mint Debian Install - Thinkpad T430s Problem

Tags: debian, linux-mint, system-installation

I wanted to try out the Linux Mint Debian. I downloaded an iso, checked it and then dd it on a usb stick.

I boot on the usb fine and Mint is starting, but then it looks like that :

[image: Mint live display problem on hd4000]

The desktop limits are halfway across the screen. The colors aren't right and are flickering. It looks like a graphic driver problem to me...
Everything seems to work fine except that.

I have a Lenovo t430s with HD4000 graphics.
I tried to start the Mint live in compatibility mode, but the same thing happened.

Could I fix this somehow?

Comment: That's strange, I have installed LMDE on my t400 with no problems. If you have switchable graphics, disable them in the BIOS and use the onboard card, that might help. Also, see [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org) a great resource for linux on thinkpads.

Comment: But you don't have hd4000 graphics on the t400, and I think it's a problem with this chipset...